# WebView app to access external LocalStorage on a sandbox'd environement

Tags: xcode, webview, appstore-sandbox

My app, [Cassius](https://pldubouilh.github.io/cassius/), is happily using an external file (i.e not in `~/Library/Application Support/`) to store webView data.

The OSX sandbox is obviously not allowing this. I thus used [this GitHub project](https://github.com/leighmcculloch/AppSandboxFileAccess) to ask the user the desired location for the file.

I can create a text file on my desktop using this, successfully going out of the sandbox, but giving a file to my WebView local storage `[webPrefs _setLocalStorageDatabasePath:myDirectory];` doesn't work.

In both cases the console report an issue `sandboxd: deny file-read-data`...

Is there a way for a sandbox'd app to use an external file as a WebView local storage?

Thank you !